# MKPolylineView's strokeColor property not responding

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I have this for my mapView:viewForOverlay: method:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{       
    MKPolylineView *overlayView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];

    overlayView.lineWidth = 8;
    overlayView.lineJoin = kCGLineJoinRound;
    overlayView.lineCap = kCGLineCapRound;
    overlayView.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    overlayView.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

    return overlayView;
}
```

The overlay works properly but for the strokeColor. It just does not appear. If I only use a strokeColor and no fillColor I don't get to see anything.

Am I missing something here because the MKOverlayPathView Class Reference says "The default drawing behavior of this class is to apply the object’s current fill attributes, fill the path, apply the current stroke attributes, and then stroke the path."